# textLabel on UITableViewHeaderFooterView no longer accessible in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, ios8

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerIndexText = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [headerIndexText.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

The above code works fine on *iOS6* and *iOS7* and has been in production for a while. However, when running on *iOS8* on the *iPhone5S simulator*, the application crashes with the following error:

> -[UIView textLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeccad20

Is this a deprecated approach to styling this label, or is this a bug in iOS8?

Comment: The API for this class hasn't changed so that doesn't seem to be it. I would normally say that this is an issue with your code (where it seems that header view is actually just a `UIView` and not a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`) but if this definitely works in earlier versions then I suspect it is an iOS 8 bug.

Comment: @StevenOjo : I used same method in my app (Build with Xcode6 GM - iOS8 SDK) and run in iPhone5 having iOS8 GM , and its work fine not getting any crash. Please try to run in real device, may be simulator cause issue.

Comment: Same issue in my app. See answer below!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. In previous iOS versions, if you had a custom header view, your delegate was not called with `willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:` for sections with your custom view, and the typecast was safe. Now apparently they'll call  you for every header, even your custom ones. Thus, the `view` parameter may be your custom UIControl, not an actual UITableViewHeaderFooterView.
To filter out the new iOS8 calls to your delegate, protect it as follows:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{
     if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {
        UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerIndexText = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
        [headerIndexText.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"This is the new iOS case where the delegate gets called on a custom view.");
    }
}
```